# Proof assistance for abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Suppose that $F$ is a subfield of a field $E$ and let $a \in E$. Define a map
$\theta :F[x] \rightarrow E$ by $\theta(f(x)) = f(a)$ for $f(x) \in F[x]$.

(1) Prove that $\theta$ is a ring homomorphism and prove that $\theta$ is one-to-one if and only if $a$ is transcendental, i.e., not algebraic.

(2) Suppose that $a$ is algebraic over $F$. Prove that there exists a unique monic polynomial $p(x)$ such that $\ker (\theta) = p(x)F[x]$.

Here is what I have so far im not sure where to go from here.

Proof: First we will show that we have a ring homomorphism than injective.Suppose that $f(x),f(y)\in F[x]$. Then by definition

$\theta (f(x))=f(a)$, and $\theta(f(y))=f(b)$ for $f(x),f(y)\in F[x]$.

Then by properties of ring homomorphism we have
$$\theta(f(x)+f(y))=\theta(f(x))+\theta(f(y))=f(a)+f(b)\in E$$

$$\theta(f(x)f(y))=\theta(f(x))\theta(f(y))=f(a)f(b)\in E$$
Therefore we have a ring homomorphism for all $f(x),f(y)\in F[x]$. Next we show that we are injective.

Comment: You should have edited the other one.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing different polynomials and different indeterminates.

One may define the map $\theta$  by saying it is *evaluation* of polynomials at a given point $a$. To prove it is a homomorphism, you have to prove simply this:
$$\text{(a)} \enspace\theta(f+g)=\theta(f)+\theta(g),\qquad\text{(b)}\enspace\theta(fg)=\theta(f)\theta(g). $$

Comment: Your statement does not help sorry. Because f(x) and f(y) are polynomials so original statement still stand to hold true . Your $\theta(f+g) =\theta(f)+\theta(g)$ and $\theta(fg)=\theta(f)\theta(g)$ fails due to you never declared what f and g are.

Comment: But $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ do not live in the same ring (unless you work with $F[x,y]$). As to  your last objection, I mentioned $f$ and $g$ are *polynomials*, and it was understood they're polynomials in $x$, since it's an answer to *your* question: I used your own convention.